# Number of connected components of the complement of a compact which is relatively compact

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, smooth-manifolds

Suppose now $X$ is a Riemann surface,$K\subset X$ is compact ,can we infer the number of  connected components of $X\setminus K$ which is relatively compact in $X$?Is it finite?

Comment: $\Bbb C$ is a Riemann surface homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$ and $K$ may be the [Hawaiian erarring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring). Therefore infinitely many components is possible.

Comment: Dear @Gae.S.,thanks for your comment!I still have one question looking forward to your solution.If in our situation,let $L$ denote the union of $K$ with the connected components of $X\setminus K$ which is relatively compact in X.Can we infer $L$ is compact in $X$?Thanks for your patience,time and assistance.

Comment: @Steve Your comment is an addiitional question, so you should officially ask a new question.